# intent.putExtra returns correct value in fragment but returns null in activity

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-studio

I need to get the `account` from **MainActivity** to add to my command in **AddModifyTask**. I used `intent.putExtra` in **MainActivity** and get `account` by `getIntent.getStringExtra` in **AddModifyTask** but it always return `null`, still the same with `getIntent.getStringExtra` in **Fragment** then it returns the correct `account` value, can anyone help me please

MainAcitivy, I need to pass `account` from here

```
Boolean result = db.checkUserNamePassword(account, password);
                    if(result==true) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("account", account);
                        Intent intent1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AddModifyTask.class);
                        intent1.putExtra("account", account);
                        startActivity(intent);
```

AddModifyTask activity where I need to pass `account` to but it just return `null`

```
public void saveTask(View v) {
        /*Checking for Empty Task*/
        if (edit_text.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0) {
            if (isModify) {
                String account = getIntent().getStringExtra("account");
                mydb.updateTask(task_id, edit_text.getText().toString(), new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(calendar.getTime()), account);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Task updated.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                String account = getIntent().getStringExtra("account");
                mydb.insertTask(edit_text.getText().toString(), new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(calendar.getTime()), account);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Added.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            finish();

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No empty.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

still the same with `getIntent.getStringExtra` in **Fragment** then it returns the correct `account` value

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);
        TextView textViewAccount = v.findViewById(R.id.textViewAccount);

        String account = getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra("account");
        textViewAccount.setText(account);
        }
        return v;
    }
```

Function `insertTask` and `updateTask` in **database**, is the problem with the statement in the **database** or the `getIntent` in the **AddModifyTask** or in both?

```
public boolean insertTask(String task, String task_at, String account) {
    Date date;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put("task", task);
    contentValues.put("task_at", task_at);
    contentValues.put("status", 0);
    contentValues.put("user", account);
    db.insert(TB_TASK, null, contentValues);
    return true;
}

    public boolean updateTask(String id, String task, String task_at, String account) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put("task", task);
        contentValues.put("task_at", task_at);
        contentValues.put("user",  account);
        db.update(TB_TASK, contentValues, "id = ? ", new String[]{id});
        return true;
    }
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Probably, your problem is here:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("account", account);
Intent intent1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AddModifyTask.class);
intent1.putExtra("account", account);
startActivity(intent);
```

You are creating `intent1` for `AddModifyTask`, but starting `intent` for `HomeActivity`.

Try something like:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AddModifyTask.class);
intent.putExtra("account", account);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: that's not it, Intent(MainActivity.this, HomeActivity.class); is to put account for Fragment, and Intent(MainActivity.this, AddModifyTask.class); is to put account for AddModifyTask, I don't know if it is possible to put account for both at the same time

Comment: You can't start two activities at the same time. Which activity your fragment belongs to?

Comment: HomeActivity bro

Comment: Do you have another way to pass account to AddmodifyTask?

Comment: Where you are actually opening AddmodifyTask? If from HomeActivity, you can pass account via intent

Comment: I open AddModifyTask from a button of another fragment, PersonalScheduleFragment, and AddModifyTask is a Activity, but thank you for your attention bro, now I have another way to solve this problem =)) thank you so much <3

Answer (score 0):

I used `SharedPreferences` instead of `intent.putExtra`

```
Boolean result = db.checkUserNamePassword(account, password);
                    if(result==true) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("account", account);
                        SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("account", MODE_PRIVATE);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
                        editor.putString("account", account);
                        editor.apply();
                        startActivity(intent);
```

at AddModifyTask

```
public void saveTask(View v) {
        /*Checking for Empty Task*/
        if (edit_text.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0) {
            if (isModify) {
                SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("account", MODE_PRIVATE);
                String account = sharedPreferences.getString("account","");
                mydb.updateTask(task_id, edit_text.getText().toString(), new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(calendar.getTime()), account);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Tác vụ đã được cập nhật.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("account", MODE_PRIVATE);
                String account = sharedPreferences.getString("account","");
                mydb.insertTask(edit_text.getText().toString(), new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(calendar.getTime()), account);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Đã thêm.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            finish();
```